# Pivot data by 52 weeks in the year and Fill in missing values with the Previous value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am trying to pivot data values by 52 weeks in the year (in the example I have used only 13 weeks), and wherever there are blank values I want to fill it with the previous value.

Test Data:

```
CREATE TABLE testdata (
    [year] INT,
    id1 VARCHAR(10),
    id2 VARCHAR(10),
    [week] INT,
    date1 DATE,
    date2 DATE
);

INSERT INTO testdata ([year], id1, id2, [week], date1, date2) VALUES
(2023, 'p1', 'p001', 1, '2023-01-01', '2023-01-01'),
(2023, 'p2', 'p002', 4, '2023-01-02', '2023-01-02'),
(2023, 'p3', 'p003', 7, '2023-01-03', '2023-01-03'),
(2023, 'p4', 'p004', 10, '2023-01-04', '2023-01-04'),
(2023, 'p5', 'p005', 13, '2023-01-05', '2023-01-05'),
(2024, 'p1', 'p001', 1, '2024-02-01', '2024-02-01'),
(2024, 'p2', 'p002', 2, '2024-02-02', '2024-02-02'),
(2024, 'p3', 'p003', 7, '2024-02-03', '2024-02-03'),
(2024, 'p4', 'p004', 10, '2024-02-04', '2024-02-04'),
(2024, 'p5', 'p005', 13, '2024-02-05', '2024-02-05');
```

I have made several attempts but I am unable to fill in the blanks with the previous values.

```
WITH WeeklyData AS (
  SELECT
    [year],
    [week],
    date1
  FROM testdata
)
, PivotedData AS (
  SELECT
    [year],
    MAX(CASE WHEN [week] = 1 THEN date1 END) AS week_1_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN [week] = 2 THEN date1 END) AS week_2_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN [week] = 3 THEN date1 END) AS week_3_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN [week] = 4 THEN date1 END) AS week_4_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN [week] = 5 THEN date1 END) AS week_5_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN [week] = 6 THEN date1 END) AS week_6_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN [week] = 7 THEN date1 END) AS week_7_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN [week] = 8 THEN date1 END) AS week_8_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN [week] = 9 THEN date1 END) AS week_9_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN [week] = 10 THEN date1 END) AS week_10_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN [week] = 11 THEN date1 END) AS week_11_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN [week] = 12 THEN date1 END) AS week_12_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN [week] = 13 THEN date1 END) AS week_13_date1
  FROM WeeklyData
  GROUP BY [year]
)
SELECT
  [year],
  COALESCE(week_1_date1, LAG(week_1_date1) OVER (ORDER BY [year])) AS week_1_date1,
  COALESCE(week_2_date1, LAG(week_2_date1) OVER (ORDER BY [year])) AS week_2_date1,
  COALESCE(week_3_date1, LAG(week_3_date1) OVER (ORDER BY [year])) AS week_3_date1,
  COALESCE(week_4_date1, LAG(week_4_date1) OVER (ORDER BY [year])) AS week_4_date1,
  COALESCE(week_5_date1, LAG(week_5_date1) OVER (ORDER BY [year])) AS week_5_date1,
  COALESCE(week_6_date1, LAG(week_6_date1) OVER (ORDER BY [year])) AS week_6_date1,
  COALESCE(week_7_date1, LAG(week_7_date1) OVER (ORDER BY [year])) AS week_7_date1,
  COALESCE(week_8_date1, LAG(week_8_date1) OVER (ORDER BY [year])) AS week_8_date1,
  COALESCE(week_9_date1, LAG(week_9_date1) OVER (ORDER BY [year])) AS week_9_date1,
  COALESCE(week_10_date1, LAG(week_10_date1) OVER (ORDER BY [year])) AS week_10_date1,
  COALESCE(week_11_date1, LAG(week_11_date1) OVER (ORDER BY [year])) AS week_11_date1,
  COALESCE(week_12_date1, LAG(week_12_date1) OVER (ORDER BY [year])) AS week_12_date1,
  COALESCE(week_13_date1, LAG(week_13_date1) OVER (ORDER BY [year])) AS week_13_date1
FROM PivotedData
ORDER BY [year];
```

Expected result: The values in red are the one's which have to be plugged into the blank fields.

[image]

If you have any suggestions that would be appreciated.

Comment: Please do not use images for data. Table markdown is provided in the editor specifically for this purpose.

Comment: And seriously, why are you trying to do this in SQL Server? All good reporting tools will do this for you.

Comment: In general, whenever you wish to fill in missing dates, you use a calendar table. Thats what they are there for.

Comment: How would I use the calendar table to fill up values which can be random dates . based on previous values?

Comment: You go an look at the 100's of examples out there showing just that.

Comment: What version of SQL server are you running? (Execute the command `SELECT @@Version`.) You should look at filling in the missing weeks by joining with a calendar table *after* you group by week, but *before* you pivot the data. If using SQL Server 2022, you can use the `LAST VALUE()` window function with the `IGNORE NULLS` option.  Another alternative that might work 98% of the time would be to use `WHEN [week] <= nn` instead of `=`. This assumes that `date1` is ascending across weeks. The week 1 case might still need further attention.

Comment: And beware that years might have a 53rd week (and perhaps even a 54th week in a leap year), depending on how you define weeks.

Comment: Show expected output in tabular manner with explanation

Comment: First correct the un-pivoted data.Fill in the missing data in un-pivoted resultset.Show us unpivoted data.After this it is easy.

Comment: @TN - apologies for a delayed response and thank you for taking the time to reply. 

It is SQL Server 2022 RTM. I will give that a go.

Comment: @KumarHarsh - thank you, good suggestion about doing it before the Pivot, The expected result was show in a screenshot but I am not sure if you are able to view this. 

I will try and see how to add a markdown table as suggested by Dale

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish your goal as follows:

1. Determine the year and week ranges needed.
2. Generate a calendar table covering those year and week ranges. The new `GENERATE_SERIES()` function helps greatly with this.
3. Left join the generated calendar with your source data and calculate the `MAX(date1)` value for each year and week combination. This may be null.
4. Use the `LAST_VALUE()` window function with the `IGNORE NULLS` option to fill in any null values with the most recent preceding available value.
5. Use either *conditional aggregation* or `PIVOT` to reorganize the data into the final column form.

Note that both the `GENERATE_SERIES()` function and the `IGNORE NULLS` option for the `LAST_VALUE()` window function are new for SQL Server 2022.

The result would be something like the following (using *conditional aggregation*):

```
SELECT
    S.year,
    MAX(CASE WHEN S.[week] = 1 THEN S.FilledDate1 END) AS week_1_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN S.[week] = 2 THEN S.FilledDate1 END) AS week_2_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN S.[week] = 3 THEN S.FilledDate1 END) AS week_3_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN S.[week] = 4 THEN S.FilledDate1 END) AS week_4_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN S.[week] = 5 THEN S.FilledDate1 END) AS week_5_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN S.[week] = 6 THEN S.FilledDate1 END) AS week_6_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN S.[week] = 7 THEN S.FilledDate1 END) AS week_7_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN S.[week] = 8 THEN S.FilledDate1 END) AS week_8_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN S.[week] = 9 THEN S.FilledDate1 END) AS week_9_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN S.[week] = 10 THEN S.FilledDate1 END) AS week_10_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN S.[week] = 11 THEN S.FilledDate1 END) AS week_11_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN S.[week] = 12 THEN S.FilledDate1 END) AS week_12_date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN S.[week] = 13 THEN S.FilledDate1 END) AS week_13_date1
FROM (
    SELECT
        S.year, S.week,
        LAST_VALUE(S.MaxDate1) IGNORE NULLS OVER(ORDER BY S.year, S.week) AS FilledDate1
    FROM (
        SELECT Y.value AS year, W.value as week, MAX(T.date1) AS MaxDate1
        FROM (
            SELECT
                MIN(T.year) AS MinYear,
                MAX(T.year) AS MaxYear,
                GREATEST(MAX(T.week), 13) AS MaxWeek  -- 13 weeks for demo purposes
            FROM testdata T
        ) RNG
        CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(RNG.MinYear, RNG.MaxYear) Y
        CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(1, RNG.MaxWeek) W
        LEFT JOIN testdata T
            ON T.year = Y.value
            AND T.week = W.value
        GROUP BY Y.value, W.value
    ) S
) S
GROUP BY S.year
ORDER BY S.year
```

or the following (using `PIVOT`):

```
SELECT
    PVT.year,
    PVT.[1] AS week_1_date1,
    PVT.[2] AS week_2_date1,
    PVT.[3] AS week_3_date1,
    PVT.[4] AS week_4_date1,
    PVT.[5] AS week_5_date1,
    PVT.[6] AS week_6_date1,
    PVT.[7] AS week_7_date1,
    PVT.[8] AS week_8_date1,
    PVT.[9] AS week_9_date1,
    PVT.[10] AS week_10_date1,
    PVT.[11] AS week_11_date1,
    PVT.[12] AS week_12_date1,
    PVT.[13] AS week_13_date1
FROM (
    SELECT
        S.year, S.week,
        LAST_VALUE(S.MaxDate1) IGNORE NULLS OVER(ORDER BY S.year, S.week) AS FilledDate1
    FROM (
        SELECT Y.value AS year, W.value as week, MAX(T.date1) AS MaxDate1
        FROM (
            SELECT
                MIN(T.year) AS MinYear,
                MAX(T.year) AS MaxYear,
                GREATEST(MAX(T.week), 13) AS MaxWeek  -- 13 weeks for demo purposes
            FROM testdata T
        ) RNG
        CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(RNG.MinYear, RNG.MaxYear) Y
        CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(1, RNG.MaxWeek) W
        LEFT JOIN testdata T
            ON T.year = Y.value
            AND T.week = W.value
        GROUP BY Y.value, W.value
    ) S
) S
PIVOT (
    MAX(S.FilledDate1)
    FOR week IN (  -- 13 weeks for demo purposes
        [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13]
    )
) PVT
ORDER BY PVT.year
```

Results (with an extra row showing carryover to a new year):

| year | week_1_date1 | week_2_date1 | week_3_date1 | week_4_date1 | week_5_date1 | week_6_date1 | week_7_date1 | week_8_date1 | week_9_date1 | week_10_date1 | week_11_date1 | week_12_date1 | week_13_date1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-05 |
| 2024 | 2024-02-01 | 2024-02-02 | 2024-02-02 | 2024-02-02 | 2024-02-02 | 2024-02-02 | 2024-02-03 | 2024-02-03 | 2024-02-03 | 2024-02-04 | 2024-02-04 | 2024-02-04 | 2024-02-05 |
| 2025 | 2024-02-05 | 2024-02-05 | 2025-03-01 | 2025-03-01 | 2025-03-01 | 2025-03-01 | 2025-03-01 | 2025-03-01 | 2025-03-01 | 2025-03-01 | 2025-03-01 | 2025-03-01 | 2025-03-01 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lT2NmGUB) for a demo